# Issue with create a user in MLRun/Iguazio via API

Tags: python, mlrun

I have a problem, how can I create user in MLRun/Iguazio system. I did not see relevant API in MLRun/Iguazio for creating the user. Unfortunately, I do not have relevant sample.

Did you solve the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solution. It is possible to create user via **IGZ-Mgmt-SDK** see [link](https://iguazio.github.io/igz-mgmt-sdk/index.html). It is short sample, how you can create a user:

```
!pip install igz-mgmt

import igz_mgmt

client = igz_mgmt.Client(access_key="<some-access-id>")
new_user = igz_mgmt.User.create(
    client,
    username="newusername",
    password="rePlaceme12@!",
    email="user@iguazio.com",
    first_name="igz-sdk",
    last_name="test",
    uid=50,
)
```